# If true: render <tr>, else: don't render that <tr>

Tags: reactjs

How do I render pricePerMeterTr only when pricePerMeter is available?

I tried with `let pricePerMeterTr = ””` but that rendered a span and threw an error. 
When is set it to `let pricePerMeterTr = <tr><td></td></tr>;` I get no errors but it renders the `<tr>`, which I don't want it to do.

```
render() {

    const { someValue, pricePerMeter } = this.state.inputValues;

    let pricePerMeterTr = <tr><td></td></tr>;

    if(pricePerMeter) {
        pricePerMeterTr = (<tr>
            <td className="text-medium">Pris per m<sup>2</sup></td>
            <td className="text-right">{pricePerMeter} kr</td>
        </tr>)
    }

    return (
        <div className="wrapper-medium hidden-sm-down">
         *H2*
          <table className="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="text-medium”>Some label</td>
                <td className="text-right”>{someValue}</td>
              </tr>
              {pricePerMeterTr}
            </tbody>
             *table footer*
          </table>
        </div>

    );
}


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `null`.

```
let pricePerMeterTr = null
```